# Not rendering components in React Js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have made a react app, here is my code and three components:

**App.js**

```
import React from "react";
import "./App.css";
import mediumCompo from "./mediumCompo";
import ldComp from "./Components/ldComp";
 
function App() {
  const viewportContext = React.createContext({});

  const ViewportProvider = ({ children }) => {
    const [width, setWidth] = React.useState(window.innerWidth);
    const [height, setHeight] = React.useState(window.innerHeight);
    const handleWindowResize = () => {
      setWidth(window.innerWidth);
      setHeight(window.innerHeight);
    };

    React.useEffect(() => {
      window.addEventListener("resize", handleWindowResize);
      return () => window.removeEventListener("resize", handleWindowResize);
    }, []);

    return (
      <viewportContext.Provider value={{ width, height }}>
        {children}
      </viewportContext.Provider>
    );
  };

  const useViewport = () => {
    const { width, height } = React.useContext(viewportContext);
    return { width, height };
  };

  const MyComponent = () => {
    const { width } = useViewport();
    const breakpoint = 900;
    return width < breakpoint ? <mediumCompo/> : <ldComp/>;
  };
  return (
    <>
      <h1>Hello</h1>
      <ViewportProvider>
        <MyComponent />
      </ViewportProvider>
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

**ldComp.jsx**

```
import React from 'react'

const ldComp = ( 
        <>
        <h1>LD</h1>
        </>
     );
export default ldComp;
```

**mediumCompo.jsx**

```
import React from 'react'

function mediumCompo() {
    return ( 
        <>
        <h1>MD</h1>
        </>
     );
}

export default mediumCompo;
```

i cannot see thisone in rendering website when i zoom in/out..

i did made this kind of website few days back and i copied my code from right there,
also it was working fine just 2 hours ago but now the main problem i can see is :

[image]

as you can see no matter where i put my components it never gets used!!
i even tried to use this exactly after `<h1>Hello</h1>` in my App.js
still not working!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's working after fixing these few mistakes.

All your React component names *MUST* be started with a capital letter:

1. `ldComp` -> `LdComp`
2. `mediumCompo` -> `MediumCompo`

Your `LdComp` is not a function. It was just a const expression. Need to be corrected to be a *Const Function Expression*:

```
import React from 'react'

const LdComp = () => ( 
        <>
        <h1>LD</h1>
        </>
);
export default LdComp;
```

Working Demo:

[image: Edit quizzical-blackburn-ldq44c]

Comment: @Fenil Patel, check this out !!